# Is there a jQuery equivalent of the Dojo mouseIndicator?

Tags: jquery, graph, dojo, flot

I am trying to add some functionality to a graph that shows the rise and fall of a terrain profile. I want something similar to the mouseIndicator used in Dojo Charts (http://jsfiddle.net/r7LsA/) that has a line that follows the cursor as it moves over certain points in the graph and displays data specific to that point (in this case the elevation).Note: the above link is just an example that came up in a search, not my fiddle code. The application on which I am working uses Knockout JS library for databinding and jQuery and it may be difficult to try and apply the Dojo library just for this single function. I am trying to find something similar to use from the jQuery library, but I am not seeing anything currently. I have looked at Flot, but is there something generic from jQuery that would work? Any suggestions?

```
 require(["dojox/charting/Chart","dojox/charting/action2d/MouseIndicator"],
    function(Chart,  MouseIndicator) {};
```

Comment: You can find a similar function which shows the data in the legend in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2rm8dnq/). Maybe you can modify this to your needs.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was looking for (I discovered Flot yesterday and that seems to be what we are using). I have a js file I put together with a simialr funtionality (specifically, I am using"plothover"). So my question is, to invoke this functionality, do I just need to put `<div id="placeholder"></div> ` in my html file that's rendering the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I realized there is, infact, a great tool called jQuery Flot which has much of the same functionality as Dojo. Here is a link to the API documentation: [FLOT API on Github](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md). Note that not all of the plugins come with the standard download. For example, flot.tooltips has to be integrated as a separate plugin. Simply using `$npm install flot` (if you choose to install it that way) will only give you the standard package. Hope this helps for anyone looking for jQuery alternatives to Dojo.